# dans le contexte des ordinateurs, qu'est-ce qu'une expression française pour "changer de mode" ?

Tags: technologie

il existe un système d'exploitation pour ordinateurs connu sous le nom de "Linux".

l'une des commandes Linux s'appelle `chmod`. J'espérais écrire du code pour un nouvel environnement shell pour Linux. Le nouveau shell autoriserait les phrases en français et en anglais pour les commandes et autoriserait l'ancienne commande `chmod`.

Ma compréhension de la langue française n'est pas suffisante pour résoudre la question suivante. En français, quelle  expression utiliserait-on pour `chmod` (mode de changement) ?

Comment: `chmod` est déjà abstrait et peu intuitif en anglais par rapport à ce que cette commande fait réellement. Je ne pense pas que j'essaierais de la traduire (elle peut très bien faire allusion à "*ch*anger de *mod*e" d'ailleurs).

Comment: Pour des raisons de cohérence, Chmod et chown (changement de droits et changement de propriétaire) devront être traités suivant la même logique (exemple : "chd" et "chp"). Mais, ajouter à Linux encore plus de commandes courtes de 2, 3 , 4 ou 5 lettres me semble apporter plus de confusion que de clarté.

Answer (score 4):

Comme déjà dit par @guillaume31 en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52849/dans-le-contexte-des-ordinateurs-quest-ce-quune-expression-fran%C3%A7aise-pour-ch#comment110716_52849), La commande ***chmod*** n'est pas particulièrement bien nommée puisqu'elle ne change pas vraiment le "mode" (d'ouverture) d'un fichier mais ses permissions ou droits d'accès.

Pour rester cohérent, on peut quand-même garder *chmod* car ***change mode*** (pas *mode de changement*, ***change*** étant ici un verbe, pas un nom) marche aussi bien en français qu'en anglais.

Sinon, on pourrait préférer ***chperm*** pour *change permissions*, mais la commande ***chmod*** étant implémentée sous ce nom depuis 52 ans, il est un peu tard pour revenir dessus.

Comment: +1 pour chperm, mais +2 pour le fait qu'il est un peu tard pour revenir dessus.